# How can I add text annotation in Bokeh?

Tags: bokeh

I'm looking for Matplotlib type [1](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/users/annotations_intro.html) text annotation in Bokeh, but I couldn't find it in the their user guide [2](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide.html) or in the references.

Comment: The answers which have been given more recently are correct and should now be 'accepted' -- if you could be a good citizen and de-select my answer, I can delete mine in favour of the more recent.  Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of version 0.12.2, to add text annotations you would use the "label" glyph.

```py
from bokeh.models import Label

p = figure(...)

mytext = Label(x=70, y=70, text='here your text')

p.add_layout(mytext)

show(p)
```

Please find a full example in the documentation:
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#userguide-annotations